# How to create an observable from Hashmap?

Tags: android, rx-java, observable

Based on [ReactiveX documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/from.html)

> the from operator can convert a Future, an Iterable, or an Array. In the case of an Iterable or an Array, the resulting Observable will emit each item contained in the Iterable or Array.

we can have an observable from an `Array` or `List` and observable emits the items in the list.

I have a `HashMap<String,Item>` and i want to iterate through the items just like making an observable with `Observable.from(List<Item>)`.

In other words, i want the observable to emit `HashMap Items`.

Is there a solution to do this?

Comment: this quite unclear what you are talking about. You may consider rephrasing your question, and perhaps adding example of desired behavior

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, however have you considered trying to create your own data structure. Maybe give some code samples of what you have tried

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can make the map entries into an Observable like this:

```
Observable<Entry<String, Item>> entries = 
    Observable.from(map.entrySet());
```

If you just want the values from the map:

```
Observable<Item> items = Observable.from(map.values());
```

Comment: And what i get each time observable emits? a set?
Nice! 
thank you!

Comment: Each emission from entries is a wrapper around a single String+Item pair from the map. entry.getKey() gives you the String and entry.getValue() gives you the Item.